# Start an EC2 instance , perform any job like mkdir test, stop same instance using php sdk

Tags: php, amazon-web-services

I like to perform following operation with aws php sdk:

1. Start an instance.
2. Now I have instance of EC2 with a linux image. I want to create a folder in its home directory.
3. stop same instance.

Is all things possible with PHP SDK only? It will be helpful if a demo code will be posted.

Comment: Starting and stopping images is possible using the [Auto Scaling class](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSSDKforPHP/latest/#i=AmazonAS) but to accomplish what you want, you may want to consider a custom startup bash script on your AMI

Answer (score -1):

For monitoring EC2 instances ( start/stop etc) AWS provides "Amazon EC2 API Tools"

http://aws.amazon.com/developertools/351

We need to just download these tools and can run them on command prompt; just like any other command.